# Performance in microservice-to-microservice data transfer

Tags: spring-boot, rest, oauth, microservices

I have controller like this:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/stats")
public class StatisticsController {

    @Autowired
    private LeadFeignClient lfc;

    private List<Lead> list;


    @GetMapping("/leads")
    private int getCount(@RequestParam(value = "count", defaultValue = "1") int countType) {

        list = lfc.getLeads(AccessToken.getToken());

        if (countType == 1) {
            return MainEngine.getCount(list);
        } else if (countType == 2) {
            return MainEngine.getCountRejected(list);
        } else if (countType == 3) {
            return MainEngine.getCountPortfolio(list);
        } else if (countType == 4) {
            return MainEngine.getCountInProgress(list);
        } else if (countType == 5) {
            return MainEngine.getCountForgotten(list);
        } else if (countType == 6) {
            return MainEngine.getCountAddedInThisMonth(list);
        } else if (countType == 7) {
            return MainEngine.getCountAddedInThisYear(list);
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException("Wrong mapping param");
        }

    }


    @GetMapping("/trends")
    private boolean getTrend() {
        return MainEngine.tendencyRising(list);
    }
```

It is basically a microservice that will handle statistics basing on list of 'Business Leads'. FeignClient is GETting list of trimmed to the required data leads. Everything is working properly.

My only concern is about performance - all of this statistics (countTypes) are going to be presented on the landing page of webapp. If i will call them one by one, does every call will retrieve lead list again and again? Or list will be somehow stored in temporary memory? I can imagine that if list become longer, it could take a while to load them.

I've tried to call them outside this method, by @PostConstruct, to populate list at the start of service, but this solution has two major problems: authentication cannot be handled by oauth token, retrieved list will be insensitive to adding/deleting leads, cause it is loaded at the beginning only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `list = lfc.getLeads(AccessToken.getToken());` will be called with each `GET` request. Either take a look at caching the responses which might be useful when you need to obtain a large volume of data often.

I'd start here: [Baeldung's: Spring cache tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cache-tutorial) which gives you an idea about the caching. Then you can take a look at the EhCache implementation or implement own interceptor putting/getting from/to external storage such as Redis.

The caching is the only way I see to resolve this: **Since the Feign client is called with a different request** (based on the token) **the data are not static and need to be cached**.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement a caching layer to improve performance. What you can do is, you can have cache preloaded immediately after application starts. This way you will have the response ready in the cache. I would suggest to go with Redis cache. But any cache will do the job.
Also, it will be better if you can move the logic of getCount() to some service class.